# Let $G=\langle (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), (2,4,3,7,5,6) \rangle$

Tags: finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G=\langle (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), (2,4,3,7,5,6) \rangle$.

I need to find sylow basis of $G$.

since the order of $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$ is 7 so we can prove that $n_7=1$ then it means that $\langle (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)\rangle\lhd G$ right? this is in the basis but how to I find the rest of the groups in the sylow basis?

I tried to find more groups in the basis, I thoght about the group $\langle (2,4,3,7,5,6)\rangle$ but she is from order 6 and we need from prime order. But I don't know how to find subgroups from order 2 and 3.

please help if you know how

Comment: $b=(2,4,3,7,5,6)$ is an element of order $6$ so $b^3$ generates a subgroup of order $2$ and $b^2$ generates a subgroup of order $3$. But how do you know there aren't Sylow-2 groups and Sylow-3 groups of higher power? You need to prove $|G|=7\times 6$.

Comment: I know how to prove that the order is 42 :)
then the sylow basis is $\langle(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)\rangle, \ \langle b^3 \rangle,\ \langle b^2 \rangle$?

Comment: @daruma , am I right? this is the sylow basis?